# Delete and filter rows in dataframe in scala which has invalid datatype content other than expected data type

Tags: scala, dataframe, validation, filter, drop

I'm new to spark and have a question regarding filtering dataframe based on dataype validation.
I want to filter and delete rows which does not have expected dataype content.

I have tried filtering like
`df.filter(row => row.schema("id").dataType == "IntegerType")` but didnt work.

Also tried below code :

```
val fileSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("english", IntegerType, true), StructField("maths", IntegerType, true)))
    var columnsToValidate1: Set[StructField] = Set[StructField]()
    fileSchema.iterator.foreach(structField => {
      //skipping columns having string datatype as it will not create any parsing issue
      if (structField.dataType != StringType)
        columnsToValidate1 = columnsToValidate1.+(structField)
    })

 val varList = new ArrayList[String]
    
    columnsToValidate1.foreach(x => {
      val columnName = x.name;
      val columnDataType = x.dataType.toString();

      val stringToBeAdd = "df(\"".concat(columnName).concat("\").cast(").concat(columnDataType).concat(")")

      varList.add(stringToBeAdd)
    })
    
    val arrayVal = varList.toString();
       
    val query = arrayVal.substring(1, arrayVal.length()-1);
   
    dataframe.select(query));
```

but dataframe.select is not working for generated query. but its working fine for

```
val newDF = df.select(df("maths").cast(IntegerType), df("english").cast(IntegerType))
```

for example :
Input DataFrame :

```
+----+----+---------+---------+
|name|  id|    email|  company|
+----+----+---------+---------+
|  n1|   1|n1@c1.com| xyz     |
|  n2|   2|n2@c1.com| 23.45   |
|  n3| mnq|n3@c1.com| abc     |
```

Output should be:

```
+----+----+---------+---------+
|name|  id|    email|  company|
+----+----+---------+---------+
|  n1|   1|n1@c1.com| xyz     |
```

Thank you in adavance

Comment: 1. When you are creating creating the data frame itself you can set the desired schema(desired types)

Comment: 2. Instead of data type filter you can do regex filter. in your use case `rlike` filter will be more suitable